# Centring 'container-fluid' slideshow & videoplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I'm having trouble centring a video in a slick slider that is playing as a 'container-fluid'. The slideshow and video cover up the complete width of the browser view fine, but when I downscale the browser itself, or test the site on a lower resolution, I can tell the video is being cropped from the right side only, thus the centre point of attraction in the video is shifted from the centre and more so to the right. Below is some screenshots indicated what I mean.

**Full Screen**
http://puu.sh/jrnmO/34b7b9eb4b.jpg

**Half Screen**
http://puu.sh/jrnot/c56f0d06c3.jpg

Anyway to make it centred according to the width of the view?
Any help is appreciated!

*//Edit*

Apologies, I should have shown some code beforehand. Below is a sample of just one slide in the slideshow. The rest are identical with different video URLs.

**HTML**

```
<!-- slide -->
      <div class="container-fluid slide">
        <video id="video1" muted loop>
          <source src="videos/Video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

      <!-- overlay -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5 title">

          <!-- title -->
          <div class= "slide-alt">
            <h3>Freelance and corporate production</h3>
            <h2>Inspire to create</h2>
            <a href="/pro/ezone/rfi/" class="btn btn-success">Get in touch</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- controls -->
        <div class="col-md-3 now-playing">
          <div class="now-playing-title">
            Now playing <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="inner">
            <a href="/pro/article/broadcast-film-making-on-the-move-webinar" class="block-link">
              <h3>Documentary Shooting Tips-</h3>
              <p>Joss Stone World Tour</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 text">
          <p>From weddings to corporate videos, Sony provides the range of professional camcorders and video production equipment that meets the requirements of every videography business. Discover creative inspiration and filming tips with our case studies, see tutorials from independent experts and find videographer events.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 in-action">
          <div class="inner">
            <h3>Your gear in action</h3>
            <a href="#" class="block-link trigger-secondary-slider">
              <img src="images/sliders/in-action-1.jpg">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
init: function() {
            var config = this.config;

            var slider = jQuery( config.target );

            slider.slick({
                infinite: false,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                dots: true,
                arrows: false,
                fade: true,
                cssEase: 'linear',
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 7990
            });

            var videos = jQuery( config.target + ' video' );

            videos.each(function( index ) {
                videos.get( index ).play();
            });
```

Charlie

Comment: Could you also post some relevant code?

Comment: pls show your html and css code

Comment: Sorry for that guys, I've added the relevant code to the original post.
Is it possible to do this via Bootstrap perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the elements' size for all the screens, you should use % when you write widths and heights.
Moreover, if you don't like the resize and need some special resize for particular screens, you can also use media queries in your .css file.

Please post your code so we can have a look and give better suggestions.